# Elasticsearch returns 0.0 for metrics sum aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Elasticsearch returns 0.0 for metrics sum aggregation. Expected output will be some of metric ***probe_http_duration_seconds***.

Elasticsearch version: **7.1.1**

Query used for aggregation:

```
GET some_metric/_search
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "range": { "time": { "gte" : "now-1m", "lt": "now" } }
      },
      {
        "match": {"name": "probe_http_duration_seconds"}
      },
      {
        "match": {"labels.instance": "some-instance"}
      }
    ]
  }
  },
  "aggs" : {
        "sum_is" : { "sum": { "field" : "value" } }
    }
}
```

The above query returns for documents followed by:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "sum_is" : {
    "value" : 0.0
  }
```

Each document in the index looks like:

```
  {
    "_index" : "some_metric-2019.12.03-000004",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "_wCjz24Bk6FPpmW1lC31",
    "_score" : 5.3475914,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "probe_http_duration_seconds",
      "time" : 1575441630181,
      "value" : 0,
      "labels" : {
        "__name__" : "probe_http_duration_seconds",
        "app" : "some-events",
        "i" : "some_metric",
        "instance" : "some-instance",
        "job" : "someproject-k8s-service",
        "kubernetes_name" : "some-events",
        "kubernetes_namespace" : "deploytest",
        "phase" : "connect",
        "t" : "type",
        "v" : "1"
      }
    }
  }
```

In query on changing ***must*** to ***should***, I get:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "sum_is" : {
    "value" : 1.5389155527088604E16
  }
}
```

The index dynamic mapping looks something like this:

```
"mappings" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [
        {
          "strings" : {
            "unmatch" : "*seconds*",
            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "to_float" : {
            "match" : "*seconds*",
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "float"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
```

However in our requirement, we need results matching all of the clauses in the query.

For metrics aggregation elasticsearch converts everything to double, still this doesn't explain result as zero.

Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks for attention.

**NOTE**: I see that in example document, ***value*** field is zero. Maybe while drafting/editing I made a mistake.

Below is the result of past 2 mins. This shows value field is actually float.

Query:

```
GET some_metric/_search?size=3
{
"_source": ["value"], 
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "range": { "time": { "gte" : "now-2m", "lt": "now" } }
      },
      {
        "match": {"name": "probe_http_duration_seconds"}
      },
      {
        "match": {"labels.instance": "some-instance"}
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 14.551308,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "some_metric-2019.12.04-000005",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7oog0G4Bk6EPplW1ibD1",
        "_score" : 14.551308,
        "_source" : {
          "value" : 0.040022423
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "some_metric-2019.12.04-000005",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "74og0G4Bk6EPplW1ibD1",
        "_score" : 14.551308,
        "_source" : {
          "value" : 3.734E-5
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "some_metric-2019.12.04-000005",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "A4og0G4Bk6EPplW1ibH1",
        "_score" : 14.551308,
        "_source" : {
          "value" : 0.015694122
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: When you use `must`, how many hits do you see in the response?

Comment: For last 5 minutes, with "must" I am getting 20 hits and "should" I am getting 10K hits.

Comment: And from those 20 hits, how many have value > 0 ?

Comment: All of them are higher than 0. Most of the values are after 2nd or 3rd decimal places,  like 0.003839167 or 0.014749622. Rarely there are values which are at 5th decimal.

Would that make a difference?

Comment: I suspect the type of that field is `integer`(because the first document that was indexed was 0). Can you double check please?

Comment: I see that in example document, value field is zero. Trust me that is an exception. Maybe I should have selected another doc as an example. Or while removing private content I might have edited it by mistake.

All values are float, as shared in my previous comment.

Updated my post with dynamic template snippet. Comment section was not allowing me to put too long content.

Comment: Can you retrieve the real mapping of the `value` field by executing `GET some_metric-2019.12.03-000004`? They might be float in your documents source, but the mapping might be different for the reason I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. I am not getting any direct field mapping for anything with float.
Only getting following thing with float. No field directly mapped as float is showing.
`
GET some_metric-2019.12.03-000004/_mapping
        {
          "to_float" : {
            "match" : "*seconds*",
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "float"
            }
          }
        }
`

Comment: Try `GET hms_metric-2019.12.04-000005` what do you get?

Comment: GET some_metric-2019.12.03-000004
some_metric-2019.12.03-000004" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "some_metric" : {
        "is_write_index" : false
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [
        {
          "strings" : {
            "unmatch" : "*seconds*",
            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "to_float" : {
            "match" : "*seconds*",
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "float"
            }

Comment: Apart from "settings" section, everything is same as I got in _mappings.

Comment: Please see the index name I gave you: `hms_metric-2019.12.04-000005` not `some_metric-2019.12.03-000004`

Comment: Val, while pasting I am replacing "actual index name" with "some" to avoid publishing unnecessary details. Otherwise it is the same. Apologies for creating confusion.

Comment: You're not showing any field mappings... just the mapping templates, so it's hard to help you.

Comment: I can share entire field mappings, but the list is too long to post. Is there a possibility I can share via chat or email?

Comment: I just need the mapping of the `value` field, nothing else

Comment: Sorry for being too slow to get what you were saying. "value" field is indeed long.

        "value" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }

But how come it is showing properly as float?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is just what you indexed in the source document. ES will never modify your source document. However, since the type is `long` as I thought then it will index that float value as a long and not as a float.

This usually happens when the very first document to be indexed has an integer value, such as 0, for instance.

You can either reindex your data with the proper mapping... Or since you have time-based indexes, just modify the dynamic template and tomorrow's index will be created correctly.